# passing single line of file to a function with the most efficiency python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I currently have a function that accepts a single input like below:

```
getterdone_func("thisismyfunc123")
```

This function makes a url request based on the input provided like below:

```
requests.get('thisismywebsite.com/thisismyfun123')
```

I have a list of millions of items I need to request from my site with the passed information.

My current thought was to use a for loop, this works, but is extremely slow. 
Bandwidth is not an issue as it is all local queries against my server.

```
for request in urlfile():
    getterdonefunc(requests)
```

I know I have used PowerShell's invoke-parallel cmdlet which provided me the ability to pass a variable, containing a list of items, to my function running that function up to a limit of 60 times.

I have looked into trying to multi-thread this but am unsure if this is the best method to make tons of requests like this. How can I speed up my rate of requests or at least speed up the passing of paths for my url in a batch mode.

Comment: I’m not sure if requests keeps connections alive by default. Does a `Session` improve performance? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Comment: The `Session` suggestion is the easiest way to get keep-alive working, you should also check your server's performance is not the limiting factor.